# Express 404 error handers with app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{}) and app.use("*", (err,req,res,next)=>{}) do not return set 404 return

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.use("/login", login);

app.use("*", (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log('errrorrrr')
  res.send('ERRORRRRR4040404040404 ******')
});

app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log('errrorrrr')
  res.send('ERRORRRRR4040404040404')
});

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`Running at port ${config.port}`);
});
```

I have set these two error handlers after the route. Instead of getting set `res.send()`, I get `Cannot GET /whynowork` on my browser with no console.log on my node.

How can I properly set the `404 Error`? I've tried just putting one of each but then it still returns `Cannot GET /whynowork` and does not go through the error handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this router after the last router you wrote, AND before the first error handling middleware (which expects `err` as first param)

```js
app.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    message: 'hi its 404'
  })
})
```

In the case you wrote above, this code should be between `login` router and `ERRORERROR...404 ******` router

```js
app.use("/login", login);

app.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    message: 'hi its 404'
  })
})

app.use("*", (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log('errrorrrr')
  res.send('ERRORRRRR4040404040404 ******')
});

app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log('errrorrrr')
  res.send('ERRORRRRR4040404040404')
});

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`Running at port ${config.port}`);
});
```